# VC dimension of $ \{ 1_{b_1 g_1(x) + \cdots + b_d g_d(x) \geq 0} , b_1, b_2 , \dots, b_d \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to VC dimension. I have to show that :

Let $g_1, \cdots, g_d$ : $\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary : show that :

$\mathcal{H} = \{ 1_{b_1 g_1(x) + \cdots + b_d g_d(x) \geq 0} , b_1, b_2 , \dots, b_d \in \mathbb{R} \}$ has VC dimension at most $d$.

I tried this but I am not sure. I take $d+1$ points $x_1, \cdots, x_{d+1}$ of $\mathcal{X}$. I note $y_i$ their labels

If I have at least two points $x_i$ and $x_j$ such that $b_1 g_1(x_i) + \cdots + b_d g_d(x_i) \geq 0$ and $b_1 g_1(x_j) + \cdots + b_d g_d(x_j) <  0$

Then I take $x_{d+1} = x_i$  and $y_{d+1} = 1_{b_1 g_1(x_j) + \cdots + b_d g_d(x_j) \geq 0}$

then $y_{d+1} \neq 1_{b_1 g_1(x_{d+1}) + \cdots + b_d g_d(x_{d+1}) \geq 0}$, and $y_{d+1}$ is missclassified.

If all of the points have the same label : ($1$ for example), I take $x_{d+1} = x_i$ ($i \in \{1,\dots,d\}$), and I take $y_{d+1} = 0$. So $x_{d+1}$ is missclassified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should cast doubt on your own idea if it doesn't use a crucial part of the assumption, in this case $d$. You can find [a proof here](https://mlweb.loria.fr/book/en/VCdimhyperplane.html).

Comment: Treat $g:=(g_1(x),\dots,g_d(x))$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the same proof follows. The relevant linear map here is $b^T g$.

Comment: Thanks indeed I think the variables are $b_i$ so the classifiers are linear.